# oracle to PostgreSQL database conversion

Tags: postgresql, oracle

In oracle:

```
select owner, constraint_name, table_name, column_name, position 
from dba_cons_columns;
```

Is there any table like `dba_cons_columns` in PostgreSQL database that we get the same information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL has the [SQL_standard `information_schema`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) which is actually a bunch of views backed by the `pg_catalog` schema.

[`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) has a fixed structure as mandated by the standard, pg_catalog is liable to change between major PostgreSQL versions.

For the information you want it's probably the table `information_schema.constraint_table_usage`.

Comment: Where i get the position(Original position of column or attribute in definition) information? @jasen

Comment: I don't know. I'd have to look in the docuimentation,